# Getting Null when sending additional data parameters to Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have seen many answers and applies all but don't get rid of this problem its not looks very hard but i don't know what I am missing.
Getting Null when sending additional data parameters to Kendo Grid ajax binding
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my HTML

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EDI.Models.Product>()
   .Name("gvProducts")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductOnSearch", "Home").Data("additionalInfo"))
                               )
                  )


 function additionalInfo() {
    return  { name: "test" };;
}
```

Here is my function

```
 public JsonResult GetProductOnSearch([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string name )
    {
        ProductContext DbContext = new ProductContext();
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;   // the main fault
       //var products = DbContext.Products.Select(p=>p.ProductID == productID);
        IEnumerable<Product> products = DbContext.Products.ToList();
        return Json(products.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution posting for reference that if anyone have the same issue can consult.
In Kendo Ui 2013 Q3 its a bug and when i upgrade to Kendo Ui 2014 Q2 716 same code works fine.
Feeling happing...